# Convert 24 time format to 12 hours format using pipe passed to ng-select angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have declared this time variable

```
const TimeInterval = [
  '00:00', '00:30', '01:00', '03:30', '04:00', '04:30', '05:00', '05:30', '06:00', '06:30', '09:00', '11:30', '12:00 ', '12:30','13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30'];
```

passing this variable to

```
 <ng-select [clearable]="false" class="form-control"
              [items]="TimeInterval" formControlName="entryTime">
</ng-select>
```

i want to change the time format at the time of display in `ng-select` not in original array like `13:00` will be shown as `1:00 PM` with the help of pipe in html component or any other way without affecting internal changes to the code.